# Replacing characters in several columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
df <- data.frame(list(Anemone=c(0, "S", "A", 0, "F", "R", 0, "F", "F"), 
                      Bivalve=c(0, 0, "R", "R", "S", 0, 0, 0, 0),
                      Bryozoa=c("A", "A", "F", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "R")))
```

I want to replace all the letters by 1, like:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(list(Anemone=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
                      Bivalve=c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                      Bryozoa=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)))
```

How can I do this??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library( stringr )
data.frame( lapply( df, 
                    stringr::str_replace, 
                    paste0(LETTERS, collapse = "|"), 
                    "1" ) )

#   Anemone Bivalve Bryozoa
# 1       0       0       1
# 2       1       0       1
# 3       1       1       1
# 4       0       1       0
# 5       1       1       0
# 6       1       0       0
# 7       0       0       0
# 8       1       0       0
# 9       1       0       1
```

You can replace the stringr-function using an anonymous function with `gsub` if you like to stick to baseR.

Answer (score 5):

In case the non letters are `0` you can use:

```
+(df != 0)
#      Anemone Bivalve Bryozoa
# [1,]       0       0       1
# [2,]       1       0       1
# [3,]       1       1       1
# [4,]       0       1       0
# [5,]       1       1       0
# [6,]       1       0       0
# [7,]       0       0       0
# [8,]       1       0       0
# [9,]       1       0       1
```

If not and the *letters are uppercase*:

```
df[sapply(df, "%in%", LETTERS)] <- 1
df
#  Anemone Bivalve Bryozoa
#1       0       0       1
#2       1       0       1
#3       1       1       1
#4       0       1       0
#5       1       1       0
#6       1       0       0
#7       0       0       0
#8       1       0       0
#9       1       0       1
```

If not then:

```
df[sapply(df, "%in%", c(letters, LETTERS))] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> list2DF(lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "^\\D+$", replacement = "1"))
  Anemone Bivalve Bryozoa
1       0       0       1
2       1       0       1
3       1       1       1
4       0       1       0
5       1       1       0
6       1       0       0
7       0       0       0
8       1       0       0
9       1       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) sub("[A-Z]", "1", x)))
df1
  Anemone Bivalve Bryozoa
1       0       0       1
2       1       0       1
3       1       1       1
4       0       1       0
5       1       1       0
6       1       0       0
7       0       0       0
8       1       0       0
9       1       0       1
```